# What is the correct way to fetch data from PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL. I created 2 tables: 1 account table that holds account data and 1 for posts.

```
CREATE TABLE account (
  id        UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  first_name     VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  last_name      VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  email          VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  password       VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL
);


CREATE TABLE posts (
  id        UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  account_id   UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v1() REFERENCES account(id),
  post         TEXT
);
```

When I try to fetch data about the user account + posts in 1 query I get this:

```
[
    {
        "id": ".....",
        "first_name": "Name",
        "last_name": "Last Name",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "post": "test"
    },
    {
        "id": "......",
        "first_name": "Name",
        "last_name": "Last Name",
        "email": "test@test.com",
        "post": "test 1"
    }
]
```

This is the function that I use to fetch the data

```
  static get_all_account_data({ id }) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      pool.query(
        `SELECT 
          account.id, 
          first_name, 
          last_name, 
          email, 
          post
          FROM account INNER JOIN posts 
          ON posts.account_id = account.id 
          WHERE account.id=$1
        `,
        [id],
        (e, response) => {
          if(e) return reject(e);
          resolve(response.rows)
        }
      )
    })
  }
```

Is this the right way of fetching the data? returning duplicate data seems bad code? I heard about sub queries. Do I need to manipulate the response to have just 1 set of account data?

Comment: where account.id = $1 will retrieve all the data which will be there in the posts table which is associated with the account ids in the account table.

From the above data you fetched I can see that these are two seperate data. If you want to fetch all the posts reated to the accounts then this is the right way

Comment: So the question in hand will be to make a function and return a new obj with just 1 set of account data and all the posts?

Comment: Please tag the language, platform or library you're using.

Comment: Maybe unrelated but there is a error (IMO) in the posts table DDL. you have "account_id uuid default uuid_generate_v1() references account(id)" but you do not want a value generated. The references means the account_id value must a value already existing in account table. If the insert does not contain the accounts.id a uuid will be generated but will never match an existing accounts.id. I think what you want is "account_id uuid not null references account(id)". Resolving a not null constraint violation will be much easier then resolving a referential integrity error.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment above:

> So the question in hand will be to make a function and return a new obj with just 1 set of account data and all the posts?

This can be done in various ways with Postgresql. One way I can think of is to use a `LATERAL JOIN` and  [aggregate](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) the "posts" into an array:

```
SELECT
    account.id,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    email,
    jsonb_agg(post) AS posts
FROM
    account
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT
            post
        FROM
            posts
        WHERE
            posts.account_id = account.id) post ON TRUE
GROUP BY
    account.id
```